# Caliburn Micro Xamarin Cross-Platform Phone Feature API's

Tags: plugins, xamarin, caliburn.micro

Does Caliburn Micro have Cross-Platform Mobile feature API's? For example; a cross-plaform way to access a Smart-Phones (Android, iOS and Windows Phone) Location, Accelerometer, Maps, Phone, Contacts or etc.?

I know its alot to ask considering that Caliburn Micro Xamarin support was only beta released around a week ago but you never know. Maybe the beta release has these features or there are plugins like [MVVM Cross has](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins)?

Answer (score 0):

There hasn't ever been a plugin system for Caliburn.Micro.  At least nothing that I can think of from version 0.x.  I don't believe there will ever be anything in the roadmap for it either.

Don't get me wrong about the abilities of the framework, its primary goal from what I started to work with it was its incredibly small foot print.  It has all the necessary bits for doing MVVM.  Some things will still be specific for use on windows (convention bindings) to controls with x:Name for example

https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/142